# Stop Caching IControllerActivator

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way to configure the **MVC3** **DependencyResolver** to stop caching the resolved **IControllerActivator**. I have several containers and multiple implementations of **IControllerActivator** registered.

Unfortunately the **DependencyResolver** is not always called to resolve the correct **IControllerActivator**. I suspect caching.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that. You would have to write your own implementation of `IControllerFactory` (perhaps deriving from `DefaultControllerFactory`) or write a delegating `IControllerActivator` that dynamically looks up your desired activator and invokes it.